# excel vba - multiline regex not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, regex, vba

In cell A1 of an excel sheet I have the following contents inside the cell:

```
select a.id, b.type, c.name 
from blah a, 
blah2 b, 
blah3 c
where a.id = b.key
and b.key = c.id
;
```

Either of the below are desired results:

```
select 1 from
blah a, 
blah2 b, 
blah3 c
where a.id = b.key
and b.key = c.id
;
```

OR

```
select 1
from blah a, 
blah2 b, 
blah3 c
where a.id = b.key
and b.key = c.id
;
```

I have this vba code

```
    Dim objRegExp As New RegExp
    objRegExp.Pattern = "select .+ from"
    objRegExp.Global = True
    objRegExp.MultiLine = True
    regexpReplace =objRegExp.Replace(Trim(Worksheets("new").Range("A1").Value),"select 1 from")
MsgBox regexpReplace
```

But the message box is displaying the exact text from cell A1 (ie with no replacement taking place). Does anyone know why this is happening? I wan't to be able to replace across multilines.

I know my regex code is ok because I tried changing cell A1 to the below (and it did the replacement properly):

```
select a.id, b.type, c.name from
blah a, 
blah2 b, 
blah3 c
where a.id = b.key
and b.key = c.id
;
```

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is probably because `.` doesn't match newlines (I'm not sure, but `.MultiLine` *should* have changed that behaviour? For whatever reason, it might not have, so try this.).

Try:

```
select.+\n*from
```

Or maybe:

```
select.+\r\n*from
```

Even better:

```
select[\s\S]+from
```

Also:

```
select[\u0000-\uFFFF]+from
```

The first two mean match everything except newlines, and also match newlines at a specific position. The last two mean match everything including newlines.

Comment: +1 for `select[\s\S]+from`.

Answer (score 4):

Try with this regex

```
select (.*?)[\r\n|\s]from
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues:

1. The regex pattern does not match the New Line ( as others have mentioned): use
   `objRegExp.Pattern = "select\s.+\sfrom"`  (`\s` to match whitespace, including new lines)
2. Change the replace pattern to `"select 1" & vbNewLine & "from"` to insert the new line where you want it